# Design color is not reflecting on the website

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website in Asp.net and I want my design color as a shade of blue #c2ddf6 it is blue until I add the **bootstrap.min.css** file

Without adding this file I am unable to get other features so how should I get both the features as well as retain the color on the website.

[bootstrap.min.css V3.0.0](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css)

My other css file has the following content

```
    body {
    background-color: #b5e1e5;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 304 304' width='304' height='304'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23a7a0b2' fill-opacity='0.4' d='M44.1 224a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H0v-2h44.1zm160 48a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H82v-2h122.1zm57.8-46a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H304v2h-42.1zm0 16a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H304v2h-42.1zm6.2-114a5 5 0 1 1 0 2h-86.2a5 5 0 1 1 0-2h86.2zm-256-48a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H0v-2h12.1zm185.8 34a5 5 0 1 1 0-2h86.2a5 5 0 1 1 0 2h-86.2zM258 12.1a5 5 0 1 1-2 0V0h2v12.1zm-64 208a5 5 0 1 1-2 0v-54.2a5 5 0 1 1 2 0v54.2zm48-198.2V80h62v2h-64V21.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zm16 16V64h46v2h-48V37.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zm-128 96V208h16v12.1a5 5 0 1 1-2 0V210h-16v-76.1a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zm-5.9-21.9a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H114v48H85.9a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H112v-48h12.1zm-6.2 130a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H176v-74.1a5 5 0 1 1 2 0V242h-60.1zm-16-64a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H114v48h10.1a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H112v-48h-10.1zM66 284.1a5 5 0 1 1-2 0V274H50v30h-2v-32h18v12.1zM236.1 176a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H226v94h48v32h-2v-30h-48v-98h12.1zm25.8-30a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H274v44.1a5 5 0 1 1-2 0V146h-10.1zm-64 96a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H208v-80h16v-14h-42.1a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H226v18h-16v80h-12.1zm86.2-210a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H272V0h2v32h10.1zM98 101.9V146H53.9a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H96v-42.1a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zM53.9 34a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H80V0h2v34H53.9zm60.1 3.9V66H82v64H69.9a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H80V64h32V37.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zM101.9 82a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H128V37.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0V82h-28.1zm16-64a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H146v44.1a5 5 0 1 1-2 0V18h-26.1zm102.2 270a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H98v14h-2v-16h124.1zM242 149.9V160h16v34h-16v62h48v48h-2v-46h-48v-66h16v-30h-16v-12.1a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zM53.9 18a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H64V2H48V0h18v18H53.9zm112 32a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H192V0h50v2h-48v48h-28.1zm-48-48a5 5 0 0 1-9.8-2h2.07a3 3 0 1 0 5.66 0H178v34h-18V21.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0V32h14V2h-58.1zm0 96a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H137l32-32h39V21.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0V66h-40.17l-32 32H117.9zm28.1 90.1a5 5 0 1 1-2 0v-76.51L175.59 80H224V21.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0V82h-49.59L146 112.41v75.69zm16 32a5 5 0 1 1-2 0v-99.51L184.59 96H300.1a5 5 0 0 1 3.9-3.9v2.07a3 3 0 0 0 0 5.66v2.07a5 5 0 0 1-3.9-3.9H185.41L162 121.41v98.69zm-144-64a5 5 0 1 1-2 0v-3.51l48-48V48h32V0h2v50H66v55.41l-48 48v2.69zM50 53.9v43.51l-48 48V208h26.1a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H0v-65.41l48-48V53.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zm-16 16V89.41l-34 34v-2.82l32-32V69.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zM12.1 32a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H9.41L0 43.41V40.6L8.59 32h3.51zm265.8 18a5 5 0 1 1 0-2h18.69l7.41-7.41v2.82L297.41 50H277.9zm-16 160a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H288v-71.41l16-16v2.82l-14 14V210h-28.1zm-208 32a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H64v-22.59L40.59 194H21.9a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H41.41L66 216.59V242H53.9zm150.2 14a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H96v-56.6L56.6 162H37.9a5 5 0 1 1 0-2h19.5L98 200.6V256h106.1zm-150.2 2a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H80v-46.59L48.59 178H21.9a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H49.41L82 208.59V258H53.9zM34 39.8v1.61L9.41 66H0v-2h8.59L32 40.59V0h2v39.8zM2 300.1a5 5 0 0 1 3.9 3.9H3.83A3 3 0 0 0 0 302.17V256h18v48h-2v-46H2v42.1zM34 241v63h-2v-62H0v-2h34v1zM17 18H0v-2h16V0h2v18h-1zm273-2h14v2h-16V0h2v16zm-32 273v15h-2v-14h-14v14h-2v-16h18v1zM0 92.1A5.02 5.02 0 0 1 6 97a5 5 0 0 1-6 4.9v-2.07a3 3 0 1 0 0-5.66V92.1zM80 272h2v32h-2v-32zm37.9 32h-2.07a3 3 0 0 0-5.66 0h-2.07a5 5 0 0 1 9.8 0zM5.9 0A5.02 5.02 0 0 1 0 5.9V3.83A3 3 0 0 0 3.83 0H5.9zm294.2 0h2.07A3 3 0 0 0 304 3.83V5.9a5 5 0 0 1-3.9-5.9zm3.9 300.1v2.07a3 3 0 0 0-1.83 1.83h-2.07a5 5 0 0 1 3.9-3.9zM97 100a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-48 32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm32 48a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm32-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0-32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm32 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16-64a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 96a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-144a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-96 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm96 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16-64a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-32 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zM49 36a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-32 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm32 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zM33 68a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-48a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 240a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16-64a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16-32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm80-176a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm32 48a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0-32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm112 176a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zM17 180a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0-32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zM17 84a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm32 64a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.myButton {
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 4px 0px 0px #8a2a21;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 4px 0px 0px #8a2a21;
    box-shadow: 3px 4px 0px 0px #8a2a21;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #db3021), color-stop(1, #f2c2bf));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #db3021 5%, #f2c2bf 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #db3021 5%, #f2c2bf 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #db3021 5%, #f2c2bf 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #db3021 5%, #f2c2bf 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #db3021 5%, #f2c2bf 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#db3021', endColorstr='#f2c2bf',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#db3021;
    -moz-border-radius:18px;
    -webkit-border-radius:18px;
    border-radius:18px;
    border:1px solid #d02718;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:17px;
    padding:7px 25px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #810e05;
}
.myButton:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #f2c2bf), color-stop(1, #db3021));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #f2c2bf 5%, #db3021 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f2c2bf 5%, #db3021 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #f2c2bf 5%, #db3021 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #f2c2bf 5%, #db3021 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #f2c2bf 5%, #db3021 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f2c2bf', endColorstr='#db3021',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#f2c2bf;
}
.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

The links that I have used are as follows:

```
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/i18n/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon-i18n.js" type="text/javascript" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <link href="Styles/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="Styles/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Prata" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.dynDateTime.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/calendar-en.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
    <link href="Styles/calendar-blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Styles/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: Bootstrap 3.3.7 is the latest version, by the way

Comment: @Blazemonger Will replacing the content with the latest version help to solve this issue?

Comment: No, you probably just need to make your custom styles more specific so they override bootstrap's. See [Specifics on CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) for a rundown on how CSS selector specificity works.

Comment: Have you loaded your custom stylesheet after the bootstrap?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what other CSS is being applied to `.myButton`.  For example, if you are using the `.btn` set of classes from Bootstrap it could be that they are overriding everything - which is a specificity issue per @Blazemonger

Comment: I will edit and post the links that I have used my custom stylesheet is before bootstrap.

Comment: Add your `<link href="Styles/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />` after the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: @CodeRomeos Thanks a lot it worked now. Also thanks everyone for feedback.

Comment: Place your stylesheet last. So there is no other link to any other `.css` file after it. Now, in order to change anything in your website, all you need to do is inspect the element, find out what selector applies the current rule and either copy/paste that selector or make another with same specificity or stronger, in your stylesheet, and your styles will apply. You do, however, need to go through the crash courses of CSS 101 and Specificity in CSS 101, of your choice.

Comment: Oh, and, as a general rule, do not use `!important`. When you use `!important` you pretty much ruin any chance you might have at developing a responsive website, considering your level in CSS. You'll need to pay good money to someone later on to recode whatever you did from scratch, responsively. And that's only one of the many bad aspects of using `!important`. CSS is clockwork. You shouldn't be using hammers.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Thanks for your advice it really makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override default classes of Bootstrap, using `!important` is not a good option as in future you may need to override your own css.

Always hook your custom stylesheet in the last. So in this case, just place your custom css after the bootstrap CDN.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="Styles/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Now this will override the bootstrap classes.

Answer (score -1):

You may use the **!important** override the CSS rules you want.

The **!important** rule is a way to make your CSS cascade but also have the rules you feel are most crucial always be applied.

You can use it like `background: #c2ddf6 !important;` to override the default background style.